# Django - social like permissions for objects

Tags: python, django, user-permissions

I'm learning Django framework and I'm trying to implement some social features / permissions for objects. What is the best solutions for such thing eg.:

We have some model (eg.: photo):

```
name_field
picture_field
owner_field
allowed_group_users_field
```

`allowed_group_users_field` <----- field where we will put gorup / users whose are able to see photo.

Now view which will handle showing pictures should use: "@user_passes_test" decorator which will check if requesting user is included in `allowed_group_users_field`.

And my question is:

Is it correct way to solve such thing or there are better solutions for that - maybe other decorator is more suitable or other way of implementation..?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome onboard!
I have a relatively new account also in stackoverflow but I have quite some experience with django.
The way i see it, you want to create groups like foreign keys one to many, to users who are allowed to see this.
Your solution with a decorator is pretty common and there is nice documentation here, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test and an example for the kind of group you need, here https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1703/.
So, all you have to do is to extend the current decorator with your own logic (if user belongs to specific group) and it will work.
I hope i answer your question!